# Unintended behavior in c++ when passing in an incremented integer to a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

The code itself accepts N and M from standard input and prints M-length combinations from 1 to N.

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int *arr, int size)
{
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
}

bool is_found(int *arr, int size, int num)
{
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
                if (num == arr[i])
                        return true;
        }
        return false;
}

void recurse(int *arr, int n, int m, int cur)
{
        if (cur >= m)
                print(arr, m);
        else
        {
                for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
                {
                        if (is_found(arr, cur + 1, i))
                                continue;
                        arr[cur] = i;
                        recurse(arr, n, m, cur + 1);
                }
        }
}

int main()
{
        int *arr;
        int n;
        int m;
        int temp;

        std::cin >> n >> m;
        arr = new int[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
                arr[i] = 0;
        recurse(arr, n, m, 0);
}
```

Eg.

```
input: 4 4
```

```
output: 
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
1 3 2 4
1 3 4 2
1 4 2 3
1 4 3 2
2 1 4 3
2 3 1 4
2 3 4 1
2 4 1 3
2 4 3 1
3 1 2 4
3 1 4 2
3 2 1 4
3 2 4 1
3 4 1 2
3 4 2 1
4 1 3 2
4 2 1 3
4 2 3 1
4 3 1 2
4 3 2 1
```

The code above works as intended.
However, in the recurse function, changing this part of the code results in unexpected behavior.

```
    arr[cur] = i;
    recurse(arr, n, m, cur + 1);
```

```
void recurse(int *arr, int n, int m, int cur)
{
        if (cur >= m)
                print(arr, m);
        else
        {
                for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
                {
                        if (is_found(arr, cur + 1, i))
                                continue;
                        // option 1 (original, works)
                        arr[cur] = i;
                        recurse(arr, n, m, cur + 1);
                        // option 2 (doesn't work)
                        arr[cur++] = i;
                        recurse(arr, n, m, cur);
                        // option 3 (doesn't work)
                        arr[cur] = i;
                        cur = cur + 1;
                        recurse(arr, n, m, cur);
```

This is the output when using **option 2** and **option 3**

```
input: 4 4
```

```
output:
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
1 3 2 4
1 3 4 2
```

My question is, aren't the three options written above equivalent? I don't understand why option 1 works as intended and options 2 and 3 don't. Why does passing in the value `cur + 1` to the recursive function work, but changing the value of `cur` before passing, doesn't?

My best guess is that it has something to do with recursion and using the same array for the recursive call, or perhaps the problem is from a completely different part of the code. But I really have no idea why this is happening.
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Notice there is [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to iterate over permutations.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh I didn't know that! The purpose here was to try and write it myself but thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
         // option 1 (original, works)
         arr[cur] = i;
         recurse(arr, n, m, cur + 1);
```

Does not modify `cur`. The loop continues with the next loop and the value of `cur` is the same in the next iteration. On the other hand, this

```
         // option 2 (doesn't work)
         arr[cur++] = i;
         recurse(arr, n, m, cur);
         // option 3 (doesn't work)
         arr[cur] = i;
         cur = cur + 1;
```

Both modify `cur` and the value wont be the same in the next iteration. I suppose the confusion is caused by recursion, but consider the same without recursion:

```
            int cur = 0;
            for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                    arr[cur] = i;
            }
```

vs

```
            int cur = 0;
            for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                    cur = cur + 1;
                    arr[cur] = i;
            }
```

Would you expect this two to be identical?